# How to add html to body in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I need to place some HTML content for body of my page using DOJO.
At the moment using the following code I cannot create the div.
Any idea what is wrong?

```
  var body = dojo.body();
  dojo.place(body, '<div>header</div>');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually switched the parameters. Correct usage is:

```
dojo.place('<div>header</div>', body);
```

So the reference node should be the second parameter.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uw2dLj57/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use dom-construct to turn strings into html and access to the body element is provided via the window module, dojo.body is deprecated:

```
require([
    'dojo/_base/window',
    'dojo/dom-construct'
], function(baseWin, domConstruct){
    // Take a string and turn it into a DOM node
    var node = domConstruct.toDom('<div>header</div>');
    // Place node at body element
    domConstruct.place(node, baseWin.body());
});
```

See the reference for `dojo/_base/window` and `dojo/dom-construct`:

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/_base/window.html#dojo-base-window-body
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/dom-construct.html